# Toggle layer in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to create a HTML page with a check list that we can also make it large without losing quality. As a result I want to use SVG.

I would like to have a script to operate on the SVG so that I can toggle the group `svg_2` (a check mark) on or off so that we have checked and unchecked box.  It doesn't have to change when loaded, just need like an inline command that will do it.

```
<svg width="20%" height="20%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="svg_1" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10%" x="2.5%" y="2.5%" width="85%" height="85%" />
    <g id="svg_2">
        <line fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="10%" x1="43.5%" y1="77.5%" x2="10.5%" y2="49.5%" id="svg_3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="bevel"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="10%" x1="95%" y1="9.5%" x2="44.5%" y2="78.5%" id="svg_4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="bevel"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to toggle the `svg_2` on or off depending on its previous state (example using JQuery):

```
$("svg").click(function() {
  if ( $('#svg_2').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
    $('#svg_2').css('visibility','visible');
  else
    $('#svg_2').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

You could also use some other CSS attribute (such as `display`).

See and try it here: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/fxa3T/)**